# Mutate with apply statement in dplyr chain

Tags: r

Let's say I want to get a count of the variables that are greater than 5 in the iris dataset *for each row*:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(n_greater=apply(.,1,function(x) length(x[(x>5)])),
         n_less=apply(.,1,function(x) length(x[(x<5)])))  ##Is incorrectly counting factor column

iris %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>%
  mutate(n_greater=apply(.,1,function(x) length(x[(x>5)])),
         n_less=apply(.,1,function(x) length(x[(x<5)]))) ##Correct, but I need the non-numeric columns (species) in the end

iris %>%
  mutate_if(is.numeric,n_greater=apply(.,1,function(x) length(x[(x>5)]))) ##Does not work
```

Note, I have also tried incorporating `which` logic into the custom function call to no success. I can do this, but would like a `dplyr` solution.

```
n_greater=apply(iris[,-1],1,function(x) length(x[(x>5)]))
n_less=apply(iris[,-1],1,function(x) length(x[(x<5)]))
final_iris=cbind(iris,n_greater,n_less) #This is it
```

Comment: I guess both the solutions are taking into consideration the `Species` column which is not numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` on a logical vector.  In the OP's solution, the logical condition is also applied on non-numeric columns as well.  Here, it is removing the non-numeric columns with `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%
     mutate(n_greater = rowSums(select_if(., is.numeric) > 5),
            n_less = (ncol(.)-1) - n_greater )
```

It may be also better to either create a column with the number of numeric columns or get the `names` of the columns that are numeric first

```
nm1 <- iris %>%
            select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
            names
iris %>%
      mutate(n_greater = rowSums(select(., nm1) > 5),
             n_less = length(nm1) - n_greater)
```

---

Or another option is to do `+` with `reduce` after creating columns with `map` and then bind the columns with the original dataset

```
library(purrr)
iris %>%
    select_if(is.numeric) %>%
    transmute(n_greater = map(., `>`, 5) %>% 
                reduce(`+`), n_less = ncol(.) - n_greater) %>% 
    bind_cols(iris, .)
```

Or instead of the `map`, we can use `mutate_all`

```
iris %>%
   select_if(is.numeric) %>%
   mutate_all(~ . > 5) %>%
   transmute(n_greater = reduce(., `+`), 
            n_less = ncol(.) - n_greater) %>%
   bind_cols(iris, .)
```

---

Just in case, a `base R` option is

```
iris$n_greater <- rowSums(iris[nm1] > 5)
iris$n_less <- length(nm1) - iris$n_greater
```

Comment: First solution ended being the best for my case. Thanks again, Should just PM you next time. It's always you answering, lol.